# jBPM 6.1 cannot resume process

Tags: java, jbpm

We can **suspend** a process instance like this :

```
org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessInstance processInstance = //...;
processInstance.setState(STATE_SUSPENDED);
```

and to **resume** it :

```
kieSession.getWorkItemManager().completeWorkItem(processInstance.getId(), params);
```

but it doesn't work! ... what is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To resume a process, use processInstance.setState( ProcessInstance.STATE_ACTIVE ). The WorkItemManager operates on workItems (web service calls, human tasks, customer handlers etc.) rather than processInstances.

Try the following code:

```
    KieSession ksession=......
    ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess(......
    //suspend:
    SuspendProcessInstanceCommand susp=new SuspendProcessInstanceCommand();
    susp.setProcessInstanceId(processInstance.getId());
    ksession.execute(susp);
    //confirm suspended:
    assertEquals(ProcessInstance.STATE_SUSPENDED, ksession.getProcessInstance(processInstance.getId()).getState());

    //resume:
    ResumeProcessInstanceCommand res=new ResumeProcessInstanceCommand();
    res.setProcessInstanceId(processInstance.getId());
    ksession.execute(res);
    //confirm active:
    assertEquals(ProcessInstance.STATE_ACTIVE, ksession.getProcessInstance(processInstance.getId()).getState());
```

Comment: OK I'm not entirely sure from which context you are executing your code, but if you have a look at the code of org.jbpm.process.instance.command.ResumeProcessInstanceCommand in the jbpm-flow project you may get a better idea of what needs to be done

Comment: Is it possible to persist the global and local variables when the server is restarted in jBPM 6?