# JBPM6: How to resume a process from the last successful node after the server crash?

Tags: java, spring, drools, jbpm, bpmn

I'm trying to implement the failover strategy when executing jbpm6 processes. My setup is the following:

- I'm using jbpm6.2.0-Final (latest stable release) with persistence enabled
- I'm constructing an instance of `org.kie.spring.factorybeans.RuntimeManagerFactoryBean` with type `SINGLETON` to get `KSession` to start/abort processes and complete/abort work items
- all beans are wired by Spring 3.2
- DB2 is used a database engine
- I use Tomcat 7.0.27

In the positive scenario everything is working as I expect. But I would like to know how to resume the process in the case of server crash. To reproduce it I started my process (described as BPMN2 file), got at some middle step and killed the Tomcat process. After that I see uncompleted process instance in the PROCESS_INSTANCE_INFO table and uncompleted work item in the WORK_ITEM_INFO table. Also there is a session in the SESSION_INFO table.

My question is: could you show me the **example of code** which would take that remaining process and resume it starting from the last node (if it is possible).

**Update**
I forgot to mention that i'm not using jbpm-console, but I'm embedding jbpm into my javaee application.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Have you gotten an answer to this?  I'm looking for a similar solution.  I posted here:  https://developer.jboss.org/message/923746#923746

Comment: Hello @T. Ujasiri, unfortunately no answer yet, but I continue working on that.

Comment: @Oleg The `jbpm6` documentation is lagging with examples and descriptions.  I am also looking for an answer for similar questions. The document is so confusing also.

Comment: Guys! Good news! :) I managed to restore the process with its state after crashing the tomcat process :) As soon as I have time I will post my solution here, I really hope 4 weeks I spent will save someone's time :)

Comment: This may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303161/jbpm-6-1-cannot-resume-process.

Comment: @Oleg Would it be possible to share your solution on how to resume a proecss after server crash? I'd like to know. Thanks!

Comment: It's very late, but I'm facing with problem as well.
@Oleg, could you please share your knowledge and solution here with us.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hello @Farzad! I am very sorry, but I am out of the context right now. If you have a github project somewhere I could try taking a look at it, but I can't promise anything, since it's been 6 years when I worked with jBPM last time :)

Comment: Thank you @Oleg for your response. Actually, because of security reason, I can't share it with you. I was wondering you remember any clue in this regard to help me.
My case regarding the resuming of the process has been stopped. I use RHPAM with spring boot. There is a process which has waiting nodes/components that cause committed data in the database as safe points. The JVM is lost for some reason during the process execution. In this scenario, how can I  resume the process from the last safe point saved, when the JVM restarts (manually/automatically)?

Comment: Hello guys, this solution looks good:
- Finding not completed processes through the following endpoint:
    [POST] server/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances

- Finding active node of the specific process via the below endpoint:
     [POST] server/admin/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/nodes/instances?activeOnly=true

- Resuming the process from the node which find in the previous step:
     [POST] server/admin/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/nodes/{nodeId}

Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize your RuntimeManager on init of your application Server it should take care of reloading and resuming the processes.
You need not worry about reloading it again by yourself.